# Send data to v-app-bar in shared layout from a different layout. Vue

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm wondering If I can setup a v-app-bar from Vuetify in the shared layout file and from the other layout send info, like for example the page title.

This is the shared layout

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <v-navigation-drawer app permanent dark color="secondary">
           //nav items in here
        </v-navigation-drawer>

        <v-content>
            <v-container fluid>
                <slot></slot>
            </v-container>
        </v-content>
    </v-app>
</template>
```

The other layout file will be placed in the `<slot></slot>` tag, this is the other layout file where the app bar is

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <layout>

            <v-app-bar absolute fixed color="white" elevate-on-scroll>
                <h2>Categories</h2>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn>New</v-btn>
            </v-app-bar>

        </layout>
    </v-app>
</template>
```

I'm not familiar with Vuetify, I'm trying to learn so is there a way to do this? Also should I have the `<v-app></v-app>` in both files or only the shared layout?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want two seperate layouts but with a similar app-bar? If possible please try and provide a minimal example (codesandbox, codepen)

Comment: @Rie the shared layout is like "wrapper" to say it one way, like the nav bar, it's the layout that every page should have, so instead of copying the same code in every page I just create one file and call it to the other files so that I don't need to repeat the code over and over

Answer (score 0):

Your usual setup would be that you initiate everything from your App.vue, which is basically your source file. From here on you can load all the components you need. If you use vue-router (recommended), then you can insert the `<router-view />` tag to display the current content of the page you're in. That way you will always have the same content (app-bar, nav drawer) above and below (footer) the `<router-view />`.

You could remove the `MyNavDrawer` component and just put the v-navigation-drawer in there directly but I feel like most navigation-drawers take up a lot of markup and having it abstracted away in a component looks a lot cleaner.

```
// App.vue
<template>
  <v-app>
    <MyNavDrawer />
    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid>
        <!-- If you use vue router -->
        <router-view />
        <!-- If you just want to display other components, add them -->
        <MyOtherComponent />
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
    <!-- Maybe add a footer here -->
    <MyFooter />
  </v-app>
</template>
<script>
import MyNavDrawer from "/path/to/myNavDrawer.vue";
import MyOtherComponent from "/path/to/myOtherComponent.vue";
import MyFooter from "/path/to/myFooter.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    MyNavDrawer,
    MyOtherComponent,
    MyFooter
  }
}
</script>


// myNavDrawer.vue
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer app permanent dark color="secondary">
    //nav items in here
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>
```